# Inconsistent ifeq and ifneq

Tags: if-statement, makefile

I can't figure out why in the following the two different versions yield different results:

```
$(INCLUDE_DIR)/%: TRGT_PATH = \
    $(INCLUDE_DIR)/$(patsubst $(word 1,$(subst /, ,$(dir $*)))/%,%,$*)
$(INCLUDE_DIR)/%: INCLUDEDS = $(TRGT_PATH)
$(INCLUDED_FILES) : $(INCLUDE_DIR)/%: %
ifeq ($(TRGT_PATH),$(findstring $(TRGT_PATH),$(INCLUDEDS)))
    @echo [INC][WARN] File $(TRGT_PATH) already exists while copying from $*
else
    @echo $(findstring $(TRGT_PATH),$(INCLUDEDS))
    @echo [INC] $* $(TRGT_PATH)
    @cp $* $(TRGT_PATH)
endif
```

Output:

```
[INC][WARN] File include/GeometricObject.h already exists while copying from engine/GeometricObject.h
[INC][WARN] File include/util.h already exists while copying from engine/util.h
[INC][WARN] File include/util.h already exists while copying from test/util.h
```

If I change the line `ifeq ($(TRGT_PATH),$(findstring $(TRGT_PATH),$(INCLUDEDS)))` to `ifneq (,$(findstring $(TRGT_PATH),$(INCLUDEDS)))` the output is:

```
include/GeometricObject.h
[INC] engine/GeometricObject.h include/GeometricObject.h
include/util.h
[INC] engine/util.h include/util.h
include/util.h
[INC] test/util.h include/util.h
```

As far as I know `$(findstring t,l)` returns the `t` if `t` is in `l` and else an empty string. But the output (if `VAR` is equals `LIST`) still is:

```
foo
bar
```

Can someone explain?

PS: I tested a more simple code and that worked fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd provided a complete example, including the values of `VAR` and `LIST`, we'd be able to help.  As it is, all I can say is "it works for me", so you must not be accurately reporting your environment in your question:

```
$ cat Makefile
VAR = v
LIST = v
all:
ifneq (,$(findstring $(VAR),$(LIST)))
        @echo foo
else
        @echo bar
endif

$ make
foo
```

ETA:

Aha.  Well, your problem has absolutely nothing to do with `findstring`, so it's not surprising that your original question was not answerable.

The issue is that you're trying to use target-specific variables in a non-recipe context, and [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) clearly states that they are not available outside of recipes.

The `ifeq`, etc. statements are like preprocessor statements: they are evaluated as the makefile is being parsed, not later when the recipes are being invoked.  So the values of `TRGT_PATH` and `INCLUDEDS` when the `ifeq`/`ifneq` is invoked are the *global* values of those variables (which might be the empty string if they're not set otherwise) not the target-specific values.